# C++ error _strupr : cannot convert parameter 1

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I recently got a project to upgrade an old dll from Visual Studio 6 to Visual Studio 2010.  I got 68 errors after the upgrade, which I have reduced down to 1.

```
MessageGroup::MessageGroup(const char *name, WordCollection *words) {
    _name.assign(name);
    _strupr( _name.begin() );
    setWordCollection(words);
}
```

error C2664: '_strupr' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::_String_iterator<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' to 'char *'

Comment: What's `_name`, `_strupr()`, `setWordCollection()` actually? Provide a [mcve] please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, _name is `std::string`, _strupr is a Windows-specific version of strupr. setWordCollection I have no idea about.

Answer (score 0):

`_strupr` expects to see the pointer to char, while _name being `std::string` and it's `begin` returns an **iterator**. To obtain the underlying pointer to characters usable for `_strupr`, use `_name.c_str()`.

However, since you can not modify const pointer returned by `c_str()`, the whole code has to be rewritten. For example:

```
MessageGroup::MessageGroup(const char *name, WordCollection *words) :
    _name(name) {
    std::transform(name.begin(), name.end(), name.begin(),
              [](char ch) { return ::toupper(ch); });
}
```

**BONUS**

Why did it work before the upgrade, you might ask? Because in the ancient VS 6, and iterator to string was a `char*`, and as such, sufficied for `_strupr()`. However, such code had a problem, since `std::string` did not have to end with '\0' back than, so your string provided to `_strupr` was not neccessary suitable for it.